# Using range with for/in

Tags: python, for-loop, range

```
#This program will calculate distance traveled

#ask for miles traveled
speed = int(input("Enter speed in mph: "))
#ask for hours traveled
hour = int(input("Enter hours traveled: "))
increment = 1


def main ():
    print ('Hours\t Distance')
    print ('----------------')

for hour in range(speed, hour, increment):
    distance = speed * hour
    print(hour, '\t' , distance)


main()
```

I know I'm looking right at the problem and just not seeing it. I can get the column headers and the separator to print, but the for statement will not run. Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your range needs to start at `0` (or maybe `increment` if you don't want `0`), not `speed`

```
for hour in range(0, hour, increment):
    distance = speed * hour
    print(hour, '\t' , distance)
```

If you want to skip the 0, you probably need this

```
for hour in range(increment, hour+increment, increment):
    distance = speed * hour
    print(hour, '\t' , distance)
```